# Resources for learning TDD and getting setup on Windows 7 for doing TDD with Rails?

Tags: windows-7, tdd, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to learn TDD, but getting RSpec + Autotest setup on Windows 7 has been a pain.

Does anyone have any good resources that can point me in the right direction of getting this thing setup, so I can continue learning how to do TDD in Rails?

Thanks.

Comment: I've now got rspec running with cucumber on Windows 7. This is using Ruby 1.8.7 and rspec 2.0 on Rails 3

Comment: Care to share the details or a link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

http://railstutorial.org/book

Comment: That's the exact tutorial I am going through, but when it comes to the part about getting setup on a Windows 7 machine, the tutorial is lacking big time.